# DataTables in Django modify columns ordering

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, datatable

I write Django app, where I have a `base.html` template and I defined var table where I declared order by column 0 with 'desc' (look below) So I currently use it some templates, where I extend base.html. But now I need to sort in new template firstly by the second column, and after that by the first column (like this: `"order": [1, 0, 'desc']` ). I don't know how I modify this variable without a duplicate code. Could somebody help me?

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 0,
      "searchable": false,
      "order": [0, 'desc'],
      "ordering": true,
    } ]
} );
```

In template which extends `'base.html'`

```
<script> 
     //modify order method
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the ordering using [.order()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) then redraw the table:

```
table.order( [ 1, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'desc' ] ).draw();
```